# CoreData : Is one-to-one relationship description workable for sortDescriptors, but not workable for propertiesToUpdate and propertiesToFetch?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have entity `NSNote` which is having one-to-one relationship with `NSContent`

The name of the relationship is `content`.

I notice the covention `content.[some properties]` workable for `sortDescriptors`, and not `propertiesToUpdate`/ `propertiesToFetch`

---

### Supported in sortDescriptors

The following is a workable code

```
let liteBodySortingSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "content.liteBodySorting", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))
let sortDescriptors = [liteBodySortingSortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
```

---

### Not workable in propertiesToUpdate

```
let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "NSPlainNote")
batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", item.objectID)
batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["content.body" : updateBody.body as Any]
batchUpdateRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType

// reason: 'Invalid string keypath content.body passed to propertiesToUpdate:'
```

---

### Not workable in propertiesToFetch

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSPlainNote>(entityName: "NSPlainNote")              
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", objectID)
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [
    "kindValue",
    "content.body",
    "content.searchedString",
    "liteBody",
    "content.liteBodySorting",
    "locked",
]

// reason: 'Bad fetch request (NSManagedObjectResultType not compatible with contents of propertiesToFetch)'
```

---

I was wondering, is my findings correct? If it is so, how I should make it work for `propertiesToUpdate` and `propertiesToFetch`?

Comment: You haven’t set `resultType` for your fetch request

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry. I didn't post complete code snippet. I updated. Previously, `propertiesToUpdate` and `propertiesToFetch` both workable, without having one-to-one notation (content.[something]). Now, after added one-to-one notation, they are no longer working. But surprising, such notation is workable in `sortDescriptors`. So, this makes me confuse. Maybe I had done something wrong?

Comment: For `propertiesToFetch`, I didn't set result type explicitly, because I am expecting returned object is NSManagedObject.

Comment: But it isn’t, you have selected attributes from different entities so you can not get NSManagedObject objects back, this must be a dictionary.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hem... I am expecting I can get a "faulted" NSNote together with "faulted" NSContent. Maybe I will change my expectation to Dictionary. By the way, do you have idea why it doesn't work for propertiesToUpdate, by work for sortDescriptors?

Comment: I don’t have much experience with doing batch updates but to me it makes sense that you can only work with one entity at a time.